# Run a command on a remote Windows Server as user

Tags: windows

I want to run a command on a remote Windows server as the user that I am logged on as in Windows.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PSEXEC command that comes with the [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) or you can use PowerShell's [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx). I'll let you check these links for the proper syntax based on your environment and the type of command that you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `psexec`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

I suggest reading the documentation and the couple of pages linked to in the documentation. There are a few gotchas, and `psexec` can be quite a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but when you logon to a remote machine and execute a command, the command does indeed run under your logged on user credentials.

You can see this happen in Task Manager

psexec, on the other hand, establishes a connection to a remote computer, and runs a command using credentials you specify in the psexec commandline - but your question sounds like you are already logged in via (RDP???) and just need to execute the command?

Did I Misunderstand your question / configuration?

Comment: I'm not logged into the remote computer.  I want to automate the running of a command on a server from a script on a client.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Powershell remoting on the target server, then use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteSeverName -ScriptBlock { some command }` from Powershell on your computer.

By default negotiate or kerberos authentication will be used so the command will run as the user who is running Powershell, without having to specify the credentials.

You could also try `rsh` if you want something that comes with the operating system but isn't Powershell, though I don't remember if it will use your existing authentication context. Since it relies on WinRM just like Powershell remoting, I think it will, but I'm on my phone and can't test it.

I don't think `psexec` does what you want since you must supply credentials to it.